# How to get relative offset of assembly instruction from `push %ebp`

Tags: c, assembly, linker, operating-system, stack

When I use `disas` in `gdb`. I may get something like this.

```
(gdb) disas bar
Dump of assembler code for function bar:
   0x08048e84 <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x08048e85 <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x08048e87 <+3>: sub    $0x8,%esp
   0x08048e8a <+6>: mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048e8d <+9>: mov    0x8(%ebp),%edx
   0x08048e90 <+12>:    add    %edx,%eax
   0x08048e92 <+14>:    mov    %eax,-0x4(%ebp)
   0x08048e95 <+17>:    mov    0x81f4074,%eax
   0x08048e9a <+22>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x08048e9d <+25>:    call   0x8048ed8 <traceback>
   0x08048ea2 <+30>:    mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048ea5 <+33>:    mov    %eax,0x8(%ebp)
   0x08048ea8 <+36>:    leave  
   0x08048ea9 <+37>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

Let say I have `0x08048ea2` in my C program. How is it possible for me to obtain the offset `<+30>` and get `0x08048e84`.

Comment: The disassembler already tells you the offsets, so it's not clear what the issue is here...

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make my question clear. I want to use the offset in my C program, how can I get that in my C programme? I got the return address `0x08048ea2` by writing a small assembly file. But I actually want to get `0x08048e84`

Comment: I am implementing the backtrace function.

Comment: So you want to scan back from a given EIP and find the start of the function?

Comment: Ah ok.  I have no idea how debuggers *actually* do it.  But I can think of two possibilities.  One is to simply maintain a map of where all functions live, and then just perform a lookup on your address.  The second is to walk the stack back to the *previous* return address, and look at instruction above that, which will be a call to the relevant function address.

Comment: Backtracing usually works by moving along the stack base pointers in BP and inspecting the stored return address, assuming your function calls have a standard prologue and use `call`.

Comment: @harold Yes, I want to get the `0x08048e84`.

Comment: @KerrekSB @OliCharlesworth Yes, I do have a table keep track of all the starting addr of functions. But the first thing is how to get the starting addr of function during runtime in my C program? I wrote a small assembly code to read the return addr of a function which give me `0x08048ea2`. But I can't get the real starting addr `0x08048e84`.

Comment: @TimothyLeung it's not possible to get the starting address, because when program is loaded in to memory, which page it would get is very difficult, But having said that, probably you could try checking the eip register

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what, exactly you are after, but backtrace functions generally look at the "stack frame" and find return addresses from there.  They then parse the list of functions looking for the immediately preceding function for each return address.  If you are in a debugger then also probably can tell what line of code the return address represents.

From here I'm not sure if the question is "how to I evaluate the stack frame" or "how do I find the 'immediately preceding function".

Stack frame generation is platform specific, but generally uses a specific register to hold an address that is a fixed position on the stack established on entry to the function.  Stack frames usually point to a location in the stack at (or just beside) the previous stack frame pointer.  This allows walking the stack using the frame pointers and evaluating the return addresses (which will usually be at a fixed position relative the the stack frame information.

Be aware that there are various optimizations the compiler can make which will affect the stack frame (two specifically: disabling stack frame generation, and the return value optimization).

Determining the address of functions is also platform dependent.  Compilers and linkers will create and manage debug symbols if asked to.  This essentially embeds a lookup table of function name and starting address that is loaded into memory for the debugger to access.  Better systems will also provide the ability to lookup symbol names in release builds.  They usually do this by having the IDE provide the function base addresses (a map file), and then figure out where the sections of code were loaded into memory.  I suspect this information is provided by OS calls, but maybe there is some other mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I have a stupid method.
Add a label like this:

```
    /* ommit some code */
    label:
    mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
    mov    %eax,0x8(%ebp)
    leave  
    ret
```

Then:

```
    lea eax, label /* eax will be 0x08048ea2 */
    lea ebx, bar  /* ebx will be 0x08048e84 */
    sub eax, ebx /* get the offset */
```